# Two-way binding with <select> loop in Svelte

Tags: svelte

Consider the following Svelte code ([try it here](https://svelte.dev/repl/573d6dee353f4e9a9a2cb3a888ca3edf?version=4.0.2)).

When I change the value of a dropdown, and then click the button to call `addFruit`, then the individual elements of `fruits` remain unchanged.

How can I implement binding for these dynamically-added elements?

```
<script>
    let options = [
        {"id": "fruit1", "name": "Apple"},
        {"id": "fruit2", "name": "Banana"},
    ];

    let fruits = [
        {"fruit_id": "fruit1"}
    ];

    function addFruit() {
        fruits.push({ fruit_id: "fruit1"});
        fruits = fruits;
        console.log(fruits);
    }
</script>

{#each fruits as fruit, i}
    <select value={fruit.fruit_id}>
    {#each options as option}
      <option value={option.id}>{option.name}</option>
    {/each}
    </select>
{/each}

<button  on:click={addFruit}>+</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now everything is one-way (into the elements). You have to add [bindings](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#bind-property) like this:

```html
<select bind:value={fruit.fruit_id}>
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried for Solving this Issue
Do u need this : [solution](https://svelte.dev/repl/4e80720e1aa2495ca28b802cfe8b5d18?version=4.0.2)

code :

```
<script>
    let options = [
        {"id": "fruit1", "name": "Apple"},
        {"id": "fruit2", "name": "Banana"},
        {"id": "fruit3", "name": "Mango"},
        {"id": "fruit4", "name": "Coco"},
    ];

    let fruits = [
        {"fruit_id": "fruit1"}
    ];

    function addFruit() {
        // fruits.push({ fruit_id: kit});
        fruits = [...fruits,{ fruit_id: kit}];
        console.log(fruits);
    }
    let kit=options[0].id;
    $: console.log(kit);
</script>


    <select bind:value={kit}>
    {#each options as option}
      <option value={option.id}>{option.name}</option>
  {/each}
    </select>

<button  on:click={addFruit}>+</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work. You have omitted the outer {#each} loop which means we only show one select element, rather than adding a new one each time.